# SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services Custom Extensions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a custom data extension which loads and works correctly for a 2008 (not r2) instance, but when updating the configuration to use the same custom data extension in rs i am getting the follow:

```
ERROR: Exception caught instantiating CDESQL report server extension: 
System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied: 
'Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.ConnectionWrapper'.
```

Cant figure this one out at all. I have gone over the policy configuration settings and all looks to be set. Has anything changes in regard to 2008 r2 reporting services and 2008?

ANY thoughts would be veyr helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK will answer this myself for anyone else that experiences this problem.

The issue surrounds customisation of the default sql data extension for reporting services and as of SSRS 2008 R2 the objects within the Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics assembly have been locked down. All the classes exposed in the Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions namespace have been changed to internal, so any such customisations will need to be rewritten.